# An extra unexpected filter condition - resource.type="gcm_log" is getting added automatically by GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

An extra unexpected filter condition (AND resource.type="gcm_log") is getting added by GCP in metric when viewed from dashboard .

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a metric with filters -  resource.type="gae_app" AND resource.labels.module_id="sampleModuleName" AND severity >="ERROR".
2. Create a dashboards and a chart. In chart, Select Resource Type : GAE Application, and Metric : use metric created in step 1. Give chart name, say "Errors in module"
3. Once chart is created, right click and select option - View Logs.
4. Expected : it should show logs for-  resource.type="gae_app" AND resource.labels.module_id="sampleModuleName" AND severity >="ERROR"
5. Actual : An extra condition (resource.type="gae_app") is getting added like -  resource.labels.module_id="sampleModuleName" AND severity >="ERROR") AND resource.type="gcm_log"

Problem : Due to this extra condition, logs do not appear. Instead, message comes - Invalid request: Unsupported resource.type: gcm_log

Comment: There seems to be a related public issue tracker case: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150272134

You can open you own public issue tracker case here https://issuetracker.google.com, once the issue is resolved Google will notify you there.

Comment: Thank you Wilfred, I referred that and google said they have fixed the issue but I am still facing that issue. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150272134#comment5